# Tried extending registers in the risc ISA(spike) but getting seg-fault

Tags: riscv

I tried extending the existing register set in the spike isa simulator by making changes to the spike isa simulator in the following files as shown in the screenshots.

[image: changes made in riscv-opc.c]

following this i made change in riscv.h

[image]

i also increased the register structure lengths in the file tc-riscv.c and changed the value of NGPR.

following this i wrote my own asm code to move data from a source to destination register and print the value of the destination register. The code snippet is attached below.

`.file   "asm_test.c"
    .section    .rodata
    .align  3
.LC0:
    .string " %d\n"
    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    add sp,sp,-32
    sd  ra,24(sp)
    sd  s0,16(sp)
    add s0,sp,32
    li  a5,5
    sw  a5,-20(s0)
    sw  zero,-24(s0)
    lw  a5,-20(s0)
    sw  a5,-24(s0)
    lw  a1,-24(s0)
    lui p0,%hi(.LC0)
    add a0,p0,%lo(.LC0)
    call    printf
    mv  p0,zero
    mv  a0,p0
    ld  ra,24(sp)
    ld  s0,16(sp)
    add sp,sp,32
    jr  ra
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 5.2.0"`

I compiled this asm code by the following command 
riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc -o asm_test asm_test.s

once i ran this code i got the following segmentation fault

```
prashantravi@ubuntu:~/rocket-chip$ spike riscv/bin/pk asm_test
z  0000000000000000 ra 00000000000105d8 sp 00000000fefff500 gp 000000000001d6d0
tp 0000000000000000 t0 0000000000000001 t1 000000000001d018 t2 0000000000000000
s0 00000000fefffb50 s1 0000000000000000 a0 0000000000000000 a1 00000000fefff3b0
a2 00000000fefff5d0 a3 000000000000000a a4 0000000000002889 a5 000000000001a000
a6 000000000001c6d0 a7 00000000fefff650 s2 00000000000004e0 s3 000000000001c530
s4 0000000000000000 s5 0000000000000000 s6 000000000001bf50 s7 0000000000000000
s8 000000000001a650 s9 0000000000000000 sA 0000000000000000 sB 0000000000000000
t3 0000000000000000 t4 0000000000000000 t5 0000000000000000 t6 0000000000000000
pc 0000000000010478 va 00000000000004e0 insn       ffffffff sr 8000000000003008
User load segfault @ 0x00000000000004e0
```

Kindly help if I'm going in the wrong direction here.

Answer (score 1):

Ravi, there is no place in binary format of opcodes to store register number >= 32. Every register is encoded in generic RISC-V as fixed number of bits:

http://riscv.org/spec/riscv-spec-v2.0.pdf
page 58  (printed page number 50) - table before RV32I Base Instruction Set

```
1 27 26 25 24 20 19 15 14 12 11 7 6 0
funct7 rs2 rs1 funct3 rd opcode R-type
imm[11:0] rs1 funct3 rd opcode I-type
imm[11:5] rs2 rs1 funct3 imm[4:0] opcode S-type
imm[12|10:5] rs2 rs1 funct3 imm[4:1|11] opcode SB-type
imm[31:12] rd opcode U-type
imm[20|10:1|11|19:12] rd opcode UJ-type
```

Every register is stored as exactly 5 bits: e.g. rd as [7:11] (bits 7 8 9 10 11). There are only 5 bits to encode every register number, and possible values are from 0 to 31.

If you want  to extend register space, you need to redefine instruction encoding. You can't do it for RV32I/RV64I, because RV32I/RV64I defines own encoding with only 32 registers.

You will need some longer encoding is you want to redefine a lot of opcodes in your new format. You may try to extend riscv with 48-bit or 64-bit command encoding ("Table 9.1: Suggested standard RISC-V instruction encoding space sizes" of http://riscv.org/spec/riscv-spec-v2.0.pdf), but this job is huge and not just "add 4 constants to register name array".